# Best practice for jshint w/ grunt and handlebars templates

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-jshint

I am working on a web-application using node/grunt for building. I am using jshint, requirejs, and handlebars.

I started with a boilerplate that runs jshint on my source code, but jshint is giving me errors for referencing pre-compiled handlebar templates in my source code (the compiled handlebar templates are unavailable to jshint). Is it an okay practice to run jshint on my "compiled" code? This seems to be the only option, however, I'm uncertain if this is good practice.

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of setting up jshint to run with handlebars. the global variable JST is declared when code is precompiled with handlebars.

The solution is to add "JST" to predef in .jshintrc.